# How do delete songs from Sony Walkman MP3 player?

Tags: mp3-player

I can delete, rename and reorganize songs by clicking on the Ubuntu desktop icon for my Walkman.  However, the changes are not evident on the player itself.  Help?

Comment: Did you make sure to empty the trash on your mp3 player?

Answer (score 1):

I have an IPod, and I have had great success using gtkpod. I dont know if it will work for you, but its probably worth a shot.

`sudo apt-get install gtkpod`

Answer (score 1):

As @DoR pointed out, when you delete the files, they are 'recycled' into the `.Trash` directory on the USB device, which is still scanned by your mp3 player. But that won't account for renamed or reorganized songs.

You can trick Rhythmbox into managing your mp3 player, by creating a file called `.is_audio_player` on the device.

```
touch /media/YOUR-MP3-PLAYER/.is_audio_player
```

*Use your own MP3 player path; use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to auto-complete this path in the terminal.*

Now when you open Rhythmbox it will show your player. This works on normal USB disks too, great for if your car sound system takes a USB disk!

[There are some](http://live.gnome.org/Rhythmbox/FAQ) options you can specify in the file too, but the defaults are sane and work on most players anyway.